# PHP max length of an array

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

What is the max length of an PHP array .. My requirement is

There are about 4000 movies in my database and there are so many users , now 1500 ( increasing) . Each member can rate the movie only once.

So I made a row in my user table that will store in which movies user rated. I m saving that in the following format

```
user_id   |  rated_films
-----------------------------------------
12        |  1111,1025,3541,2354,1584,3691,2451
```

Each time when an user hit of rating button I will check with this column ..

Is it the correct way. And I am wondering if I made a separate table for this rating like

```
user_id  |  Film_id
---------------------
12       |  10245
12       |  20145
```

Is thhis will hang the process of the application ? Suppose if all users will rate all the movies

Please help me with the correct code

Thanks

Comment: you are only limited with `memory_limit`. so i'd prefer second approach since it's much better for joining tables and putting some logic into sql

Comment: Either way, you will want to *normalize* your table and go with the second option. Anything else will become a mess and paint you into a corner sooner or later.

Comment: I dont understand, what your question has to do with PHP arrays. Regarding your database layout: the 2nd way is the standard normalized way, to store this kind of information. And it will be the better way in nearly every scenario.

Comment: If you go with the first option, you will never know how many and which users have rated which film. Say you open a page with film X and want to list all users that have rated... you just can't construct a query that will return that info. (Well, you could get this info, but in a resource intensive/expensive way). So as others said - second way.

Comment: If you're using really big arrays, can I recommend looking at [Judy Arrays](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.judy.php)

Comment: Thanks guys for the help .. My only requirement is that t check if that user ( named "A") had rated the movie "X" .. 
My only concern is that for this simple information am I need to keep this much a big table ( in second solution ) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second solution is the way to go with a many-to-many relation table. The first solution is far to kludgey. It seems unlikely every user will rate every movie and your queries will probably be more contained anyway so it should be easy for mysql to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no limit. The problem is the memory. you can edit the memory php is allowed to user in the php.ini. In my opionion you should not use an array for this task. It is a database task.
If you need something in array you should use a limit.